# Unable to figure out "No module named 'paddle.fluid'" , this is with regards to the paddleOCR installation on ubuntu 16.04. Details have been provided

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr, ubuntu-16.04, paddle-paddle

**File "/robust/envs/robust/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paddleocr/tools/infer/utility.py", line 20, in 
from paddle.fluid.core import PaddleTensor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paddle.fluid'**

I am trying to use paddleocr on linux 16.04.

unfortunately while running this :
**ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en')** got this error.

**Versions :**

Python - 3.9

paddlepaddle - 2.0.0rc0

pip - 20.3.3

Here Robust is my virtual env created using conda .

Unable to solve to issue.

I found this thread
https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/paddle2onnx/issues/36
But this doesn't solve the issue.

While this works fine on win

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try the latest the PaddleOCR models, which does not have the problem.

What's more, paddlepaddle with 2.3.1 version is a better choice.